# Convert GetEntity().GetContent() from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#

I need to convert the following code from Java to C# when I'm using restAPI in C#.

In java :

```
HttpGet statusGet = new HttpGet(fileUrl);
    statusGet.setHeader("X-API-TOKEN", API_TOKEN);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(statusGet);

    // Extract exported file
    ZipInputStream zs = new ZipInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

In C# this is what I have:

```
            var client1 = new RestClient(fileUrl);
            var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request1.AddHeader("X-API-TOKEN", "API_TOKEN");
            request1.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request1.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"format\" : \"csv\",\n\t\"surveyId\" : \"_surveyId\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse responsedata = client1.Execute(request1);

var download=client1.DownloadData(request1);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(download);
ZipInputStream zs = new ZipInputStream(stream);
using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zs))
```

I have no clue how to implement response.getEntity().getContent(). I believe it is getting the Stream(Containing a zip file?)
Updated: So I get the byte array from client1.DownloadData(request1), looks like it is not right to convert it to stream (has readtimeout exception). and it will not be able to read from zipfile.read
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any specific errors? It looks like you are implementing this using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). Have you followed their examples and read through their documentation?

I have not personally used this third-party solution, but immediately on their front page they have the following example that does exactly what you are trying to do:

> ```
> var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
> // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
>
> var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
> request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
> request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource
>
> // easily add HTTP Headers
> request.AddHeader("header", "value");
>
> // add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
> request.AddFile(path);
>
> // execute the request
> IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
> var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
>
> // or automatically deserialize result
> // return content type is sniffed but can be explicitly set via RestClient.AddHandler();
> RestResponse<Person> response2 = client.Execute<Person>(request);
> var name = response2.Data.Name;
>
> // easy async support
> client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
>     Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
> });
>
> // async with deserialization
> var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<Person>(request, response => {
>     Console.WriteLine(response.Data.Name);
> });
>
> // abort the request on demand
> asyncHandle.Abort();
> ```

It looks like you would want to access the `IRestResponse.Content` property, or to deserialize using the `RestClient.Execute<T>(RestRequest request)` function.

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right. I was told it is going to return a zip file. I assume IRestResponse.Content containing a zip file? But it is as a string right now. Do you think I can deserialize that? Thank you gmiley

Comment: No you would probably just want to use the content as a string and write it out as a file to your filesystem using a using classes/functions within the `System.IO` namespace. You only deserialize to a class if you are expecting a class. If you are receiving file content you would usually receive it as a `string` or possibly a `Stream` of some kind.

Comment: @shakedong93 did this answer help clear up your problem?

Comment: gmiley sorry for delay response. It doesn't solve the problem. I tried to put the response as rawbytes and convert to stream. when it going through the zilfile, it won't read it correctly. Also, that stream has a readtimeout and writetimeout exception. Please see the updated post